# xaml automatic align of a textbox inside a RelativePanel

Tags: xaml, textbox, visual-studio-2015

I have a TextBox inside a RelativePanel in a universal Win App in C# (XAML/vs2015).

I want the textbox to be always on the right end of the panel, even when the form size changes.

Please tell me how to do that

thank you

Comment: Without seeing your whole layout this is a tough one to diagnose amigo. A generic answer would be to add `RelativePanel.AlignRightWithPanel="True"` to your TextBox.

Comment: Works fine, thank you so much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well since the generic answer did the trick without needing any further detail, might as well enter it as an answer so other viewers know you got sorted and skip the question.

Since it's a child of the RelativePanel you need to supply the declaration to the element, in this case TextBox using the bool property set to true of;

```
RelativePanel.AlignRightWithPanel="True"
```

Glad you got a remedy, have a great weekend!

Comment: And your answer deserves to be accepted..
Muchas gracias!!